# Conflict IEEE Access template with Arabic language

Tags: ieeeaccess

I'm trying to insert Arabic words within English text, I have downloaded the template from the journal site below:

https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

I get the below error when I trying to insert Arabic words:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ش (U+0634)
```

I have read an article recommended to use :

```
\usepackage[arabic,USenglish]{babel}
```

When I call "\usepackage[arabic,USenglish]{babel}" , I get more than 20 errors, :(

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,USenglish]{babel}
```

Errors list :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\thesubsection ... \c@section .\number \c@chapter
}\protect \else \protect \...
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
}
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\thesubsection ...ect \textLR {\number \c@chapter
.\number \c@section .\numb...
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
.
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\thesubsection ... \c@section .\number \c@chapter
}\protect \else \protect \...
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
}
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\thesubsection ...ect \textLR {\number \c@chapter
.\number \c@section .\numb...
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
.
l.452 \subsection{Copyright Form}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Comment: See here for a less intrusive way to write a bit arabic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529681/cant-write-in-arabic-package-babel-error-language-definition-file-main-arabic/529706?r=SearchResults#529706

Answer (score 0):

Use the arabtex package with the utf8 package and encoding

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
```

Then you can simply input Arabic text between `\RL{}` like `\RL{مرحبا}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).