# Arabtex conflict with IEEE access template?

Tags: arabtex

I am trying to add some Arabic words to IEEE access template. I am using Arabtex but it is producing all kind of errors. Can anyone help I see someone asked the same question, but I don't get the answer.
this is the beginning of the file I am trying to run.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: which answer is that?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am getting many errors I am using Overleaf but the main error is Argument of \year has an extra}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529900/conflict-ieee-access-template-with-arabic-language

Comment: I think you need to revert `\arabic` to the stadard definition (arabic numerals 1,2,3) not switching to arabic script

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am trying to add some words in Arabic into the English transcript !

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299875/endabstract-conflicts-with-arabtext-package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried this command, but it is not working! \def\endabstract{\egroup} do I need to make changes as this command for Elsevier class and I am working with IEEEaccess class.

Comment: Your specifc problem here is `\year`  which you need to protect (yes the elsevier ref was just a hint of the kind of thing to look out for)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not a latex expert can you give the instruction I really need help in these thanks in advance

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this fixed some of the errors, but I am getting new errors LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 48 ended by \end{abstract}.

Comment: @egreg the page you mention solves the problem for package forest, but it doesn't solve it for the package arabtex however arabtex package is mentioned in the context I tried the same code, and I am getting an error. so my problem remains unsolved

Comment: @AymanMahgoub You need to issue the two `\let` commands before loading `arabtex`.

Answer (score 1):

The ieee class (possibly unwisely) redefines the primitive `\year` you can define it back and save the ieee definition as `\ieeyear`

```
\let\origyear\year
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\let\ieeyear\year
\let\year\origyear
\usepackage{arabtex}


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicate question.

Comment: @egreg I was sure it was but my search foo failed me...