# Babel and documentclass conflicts for multi-language document

Tags: babel, arabic

I will be submitting an ACM article next month and am having issues with it. The article requires the use of the `acmart` document class (link to download [here](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-master.zip)). I need to be able to present words and sentences in several languages (English, Russian, Arabic, Chinese). After searching, I came across a likely-looking option using Babel, and indeed for the simple example below everything compiles as expected:

Example 1:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,russian,main=english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Test foreign languages:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Russian: \foreignlanguage{russian}{Я} (should work for Babel options 1, 2)
    \item Arabic: \foreignlanguage{arabic}{و} (should only work for Babel option 2)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The problems occurs when I incorporate the required documentclass into the above. The changes to the code above are made in here

Example 2:

```latex
% Following babel documentation / stackexchange 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529681
% http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf pp6

% \PassOptionsToPackage{russian,arabic,main=english}{babel}
% ----- DOCUMENTCLASS OPTIONS -----
% A simple latex style
% \documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}  % Documentlcass option 1 (works with Babel options 1, 2)
% The required documentclass for the contribution
\documentclass[manuscript]{acmart}  % Documentclass option 2 (works only with Babel option 1)
% --- END DOCUMENTCLASS OPTIONS ---

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,LAE,T1]{fontenc}

% ---- BABEL OPTIONS (choose one) ----
% When un-commented, the babel options below builds as expected 
% \usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}  % Babel option 1
% This toggles the inclusion of Arabic, but causes many errors
\usepackage[arabic,russian,main=english]{babel}   % Babel option 2
% -- END BABEL OPTIONS --

\author{Annonymous Author}
\email{anonymous@institution.domain}
\orcid{1234-1234-1234}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{institution name}
  \streetaddress{street address}
  \city{city}
  \state{state}
  \postcode{postcode}
}

\title{title}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}abs\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Test}

When `Babel option 2' active, the section number is wrong: it should be `1 TEST', 
but gets compiled to `0.1 TEST'. Many errors accompany it, relating to counter 
definitions etc. 

Test foreign languages:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Russian: \foreignlanguage{russian}{Я} (should work for Babel options 1, 2)
    \item Arabic: \foreignlanguage{arabic}{و} (should only work for Babel option 2)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The outputted document *almost* adheres to my expectataions: the Russian and Arabic letters are displayed as expected, but the section counters are now wrong. In the case of Example 1 the section name is `1 TEST` but for Example 2, the section name is `0.1 TEST`. If I add figures, tables, algorithms, theorems, etc, they all also get prefixed with `0.'. Although I could probably fix this by re-defining everything, re-defining the documentclass doesn't feel like the right thing to do...

I've tried several things:

- If I remove `arabic` from the babel package options, and remove the Arabic item from the list (ie only English and Russian) the document compiles fine. This indicates that the cause of my issues are conflicts with Arabic babel. Unfortunately, I will need to add Arabic text to my document, so can't do this.
- I read around and came across similar issues (eg [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529681)) which talk about conflicts with certain languages. I followed their advice and added options like `\PassOptionsToPackage{russian,arabic,main=english}{babel}` before `\documentclass`. You can see the skeleton of this in Example 2 (Babel options 1 and 2 were commented out).
- I tried using `arabxetex` and this works beautifully for embedding the foreign languages, but unfortunately this packages requires XeLaTeX (I believe) which isn't compatible with the documentclass.

It feels like there are conflicting definitions here. While I have a reasonable amount of experience writing Latex documents, I must admit to being a fish out of water with this particular type of error. Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can try and resolve this? Have I mis-used `PassOptionsToPackage`?

---

I'm compiling on Overleaf (with documentclass option 2, babel option 2, and not using PassOptionsToPackage), and the following errors are thrown (they all refer to the `\section{Test}` in the code above).

[image: Screenshot of compile errors]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

Comment: Outstanding - thank you so much! For convenience i wrote a simple command `\newcommand{\arabictext}[1]{\bgroup\beginR\fontencoding{LAE}\selectfont #1 \endR\par\egroup}` so i can do `\arabictext{شكرا}`