# Caption problem with babel in IEEEtran class

Tags: captions, babel, ieeetran

I'm using babel package to use Persian characters in an English IEEE article:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,farsi,main=english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\title{Former Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author1, Name1; Surname1, Name1}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{mailaddress1@server.com, mailaddress2@server.com}
}

\begin{document}
    
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            Here's where you place the "abstract"
        \end{abstract}
    \section{introduction}
    some Persian text \FR{فروشگاه}
    
    \begin{table}[!t]
    % increase table row spacing, adjust to taste
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{An Example of a Table}
    \label{table_example}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
    \hline
    One & Two\\
    \hline
    Three & Four\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

But I face this error while using captions for tables:

```
Undefined control sequence. \caption
Missing number, treated as zero. \caption
```

Additionally, I faced the same error for the sections and subsections but handled that with **\renewcommand** but I couldn't use the same solution for the caption.

I'm using texLive2021 and PdfLatex compiler.

Comment: arabic and farsi redefine many commands and clash heavily with special classes like IEEEtran. If you only want a few arabic words switch only the font and direction locally, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It worked but how can I change the font? I want to use modern fonts like B Yas or B Nazanin which are installed on my system.

Comment: you would need an engine like lualatex or xelatex. But your class ieeetran is basically pdflatex only. You will have to adapt the fonts, search the site for some questions and answers about this. And  if you are writing for a submission ask them first if they accept a lualatex document.

Comment: Actually, I faced issues with LAE because it only supports Arabic words but not Persian ones. What's the difference between LAE and LFE? 
I can't use Xelatex and Lualatex because they change the whole ieee style too. So it seems that I have to stick to the PdfLatex and deal with Babel. I just need to handle the captions.

Comment: Don't use the babel options! They change too much (and not only the captions). Change only the fonts, for farsi using lfe seems to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer the Problem is solved.
It's better not to use babel and only change the font and direction as below:

### Arabic

LAE font encoding should be used.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}

\title{Former Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author1, Name1; Surname1, Name1}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{mailaddress1@server.com, mailaddress2@server.com}
}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        Here's where you place the "abstract"
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{introduction}
    
    While were are using
    \bgroup\beginR\fontencoding{LAE}
    \selectfont سلام \endR\egroup 
    This is a simple text.
    
    \begin{table}[!t]
        % increase table row spacing, adjust to taste
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \caption{An Example of a Table}
        \label{table_example}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
            \hline
            One & Two\\
            \hline
            Three & Four\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Persian

LFE should be used:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% LFE should be imported with LAE or you will face error.
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,T1]{fontenc}

\title{Former Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author1, Name1; Surname1, Name1}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{mailaddress1@server.com, mailaddress2@server.com}
}
    \TeXXeTstate=1
\begin{document}
    
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            Here's where you place the "abstract"
        \end{abstract}
    
    \section{introduction}

        While were are using
        \bgroup\beginR\fontencoding{LFE}
        \selectfont متن فارسی \endR\egroup 
         This is not applicable
    
    \begin{table}[!t]
    % increase table row spacing, adjust to taste
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{An Example of a Table}
    \label{table_example}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
    \hline
    One & Two\\
    \hline
    Three & Four\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```