# arabic in english file in LaTex

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, arabic

I want to add an Arabic paragraph in an English LaTex file
I tried using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

But when I write the Arabic text it gives me an error

I also tried this one:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}

\< العربية>
```

but I can only write one word or a line using this one.

I also tryed:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}

\begin{document}
\textarabic{النص العربي} 
\end{document}
```

but this one I got the error in \usepackage{polyglossia}

can anyone help.

I use pdfLaTeX compiler.

Comment: Welcome to text.se. Does this help: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Arabic ? (I don't have Overleaf) For `polyglossia`, you need to tell it which font to use e.g., `\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]`, and compile with xelatex/lualatex.

Comment: If you want to stick to pdflatex and have only a few arabic words, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

Comment: I tried those but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For just a few paragraphs, here is an option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\babelprovide{arabic}
\addto\extrasarabic{\fontencoding{LAE}\selectfont}
\addto\noextrasarabic{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo.

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
لكن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل هذه الأفكار المغلوطة حول استنكار النشوة
وتمجيد الألم نشأت بالفعل، وسأعرض لك التفاصيل لتكتشف حقيقة وأساس تلك
السعادة البشرية، فلا أحد يرفض أو يكره أو يتجنب الشعور بالسعادة، ولكن
بفضل هؤلاء الأشخاص الذين لا يدركون بأن السعادة لا بد أن نستشعرها بصورة
أكثر عقلانية ومنطقية فيعرضهم هذا لمواجهة الظروف الأليمة.
\end{otherlanguage}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked.