# to write a pedigree in other language

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, languages, arabic

I want to creat a pedigree, but I try to write the text and comments in arabic instead of German or English.

So I tried in many ways to let it work with arabic for example with \usepackage{arabtex} and so on.
But I Failed till yet. I hope you can help me with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\usepackage{marvosym,pifont,mathptmx,courier}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\gtrset{language=german}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Stammtafel der Karolinger},
  pdfauthor={Thomas F. Sturm},
  pdfsubject={genealogy trees and graphs},
  pdfkeywords={genealogy, trees}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{inctext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytreeinput[
  timeflow=down,
  processing=database,
  database format=medium marriage below,
  date format=d.M.yyyy,
  %
  level distance=1cm,
  level size=3.5cm,
  node size from=2.5cm to 5cm,
  level 0/.style={level distance=2cm},
  %
  name font=\bfseries,
  nick code=\flqq #1\frqq,
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt, \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
        underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom DBimage]
                ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    }{},
  },
  %
  tcbset={bleach p/.code={%
    \gtrifpnode{\tcbset{colback=tcbcolback!33!white}}{}%
  }},
]{example.karolinger.graph}

%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill overzoom image=blueshade.png]
  ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1.16cm]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle ([xshift=1.16cm,yshift=1cm]current bounding box.north east);
\path[fill=white,opacity=0.85] (current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{scope}

\path[draw=gtr_Blue_2,double,line width=2pt,double distance=1pt,rounded corners=6pt]
  ([xshift=3mm,yshift=3mm]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=-3mm]current bounding box.north east);

\node[below right] at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]current bounding box.north west) {
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=16cm,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
    boxrule=0.4pt,arc=2pt,drop lifted shadow,
    colback=gtr_Yellow_Back,colframe=gtr_Blue_1,
    segmentation style={solid,shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm},
    ]
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries\Large\color{gtr_Blue_2} Stammtafel der Karolinger
  \end{center}
  Um die Zuordnung zu den Familien zu erleichtern, wurden
  k\"unstliche Familiennamen wie Karolinger, Liudolfinger, etc.
  verwendet.\par\medskip
  \gtrSymbolsLegend[german]
  \tcblower
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries\Large\color{gtr_Blue_2} Pedigree chart of the Carolingian dynasty
  \end{center}
  To ease the assignment to families, artificial surnames like
  Karolinger, Liudolfinger, etc. are used.\par\medskip
  \gtrSymbolsLegend[english]
  \end{tcolorbox}
};

\node[above left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]current bounding box.south east)
  {\sffamily\small created with \texttt{genealogytree}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}

\end{document}
```

example of a content of *.graph

```
sandclock{
  child[id=GauaOsth1805]{
    p[id=OsthJoha1780]{
      female,
      name={\pref{Johanna} Elisabeth Rosina \surn{Osthoff}},
      birth={1780-05-08}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      marriage={1805-10-09}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1809-10-11}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
      comment={Wei\ss{}gerberstochter},
    }
    g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
      male,
      name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
      birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
      profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
      image={Carl_Friedrich_Gauss.jpg},
    }
    c[id=GauxCarl1806]{
      male,
      name={\pref{Carl} Joseph \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
      birth={1806-08-21}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1873-07-04}{Hannover (Niedersachsen)},
    }
    c[id=GauxWilh1808]{
      female,
      name={\pref{Wilhelmina} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
      birth={1808-02-29}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1840-08-12}{T\"ubingen (Baden-W\"urttemberg)},
    }
    c[id=GauxLudw1809]{
      male,
      name={\pref{Ludwig} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
      birth={1809-09-10}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1810-03-01}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
    }
    union[id=GauaWald1810]{
      p[id=WaldFrie1788]{
        female,
        name={\pref{Friederica} Wilhelmine \surn{Waldeck}},
        birth={1788-04-15}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        marriage={1810-08-14}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        death={1831-09-12}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        comment={Rechtswissenschaftlerstochter},
      }
      c[id=GauxEuge1811]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Eugen} Peter Samuel Marius \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
        birth={1811-07-29}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        death={1896-07-04}{Columbia (Missouri)},
        profession={Rechtswissenschaftler, Kaufmann},
      }
      c[id=GauxWilh1813]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Wilhelm} August Carl Matthias \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
        birth={1813-10-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        death={1879-08-23}{St. Louis (Missouri)},
      }
      c[id=GauxTher1816]{
        female,
        name={Henriette Wilhelmine Karoline \pref{Therese} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
        birth={1816-06-09}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        death={1864-02-11}{Dresden (Sachsen)},
      }
    }
  }
  parent[id=GoosEgge1735]{
    g[id=GauxGebh1743]{
      male,
      name={\pref{Gebhard} Dietrich \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
      birth={1743-02-13}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1808-04-14}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
      profession={G\"artner, Wasserkunstmeister, Rechnungsf\"uhrer},
    }
    parent[id=GoosLbtk1705]{
      g[id=GoosJyrg1715]{
        male,
        name={\pref{J\"urgen} \surn{Gooss}},
        birth={1715}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
        death={1774-07-05}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
        profession={Lehmmaurer},
      }
      p[id=GoosHinr1655]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Hinrich} \surn{Gooss}},
        birth={(caAD)1655}{},
        death={1726-10-25}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
      }
      p[id=LxtkKath1674]{
        female,
        name={\pref{Katharina} \surn{L\"utken}},
        birth={1674-08-19}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
        marriage={1705-11-24}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
        death={1749-04-15}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
      }
    }
    p[id=EggeKath1710]{
      female,
      name={\pref{Katharina} Magdalena \surn{Eggenlings}},
      birth={(caAD)1710}{Rethen},
      marriage={(caAD)1735}{V\"olkenrode (Niedersachen)},
      death={1774-04-03}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
    }
  }
  parent[id=BentKron1740]{
    g[id=BenzDoro1743]{
      female,
      name={\pref{Dorothea} \surn{Benze}},
      birth={1743-06-18}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
      marriage={1776-04-25}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
      death={1839-04-18}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
      comment={Steinhauerstochter},
    }
    parent[id=BentBbbb1740]{
      g[id=BentChri1717]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Christoph} \surn{Bentze}},
        birth={1717}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
        death={1748-09-01}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
        profession={Steinhauer},
      }
      p[id=BentAndr1687]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Andreas} \surn{Bentze}},
        birth={1687-02}{},
        death={(caAD)1750}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
      }
    }
    p[id=KronKath1710]{
      female,
      name={\pref{Katharina} \surn{Krone}},
      birth={(caAD)1710}{},
      death={1743/}{Velpke (Niedersachsen)},
    }
  }
}
```

I got the content from:  https://ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree?lang=en

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605124/5735 .

Comment: Unfortunately It don't work :(