# Prevent processing of arabic text in sections

Tags: sectioning, code, html, arabtex

**Background**

I am using the package `arabtex` to process arabic text in coding examples. However, in my main file, every time I do this the code (for example `<!DOCTYPE html>`) in `\section{}` gets processed by the `arabtex` package.

I tried to replicate the issue, but I do not seem to get this problem if I do not use a special document class.

**Question**

Is there a way to tell `arabtex` package to not process code in section headings?

As seen in the below MWE, the code is written as `\< h_dh al-l.gT al-rbyT>` and for some reason it seems to impact `\section{Document type <!DOCTYPE html>}`.

**Desired output**

To prevent / escape the code inside `\section{}` from being impacted by other packages.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[OT6,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

%: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%: Arabic font support - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX
%: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\makeatother

\usepackage{arabtex}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{editorGray}{gray}{0}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.75, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorDarkOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 0.9, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HTML
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  alsoletter={!-'}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Code style
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,
  frame=l,
  float,
  belowskip=0pt,
  escapeinside=`',
  % Line numbers
  framesep=5pt,
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Code design
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  keywordstyle=[1]\color{editorPink},
  keywordstyle=[7]\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  % Code
  language=HTML5,
  alsodigit={.:},
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keepspaces=true,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false
}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Color style for < and > for code examples
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\gdef\lst@BeginTag{%
    \lst@DelimOpen
        \lst@ifextags\else
        {\let\lst@ifkeywords\iftrue
         \lst@ifmarkfirstintag\lst@firstintagtrue\fi\color{editorBlue}}}
\gdef\lst@EndTag{\lst@DelimClose\lst@ifextags\else\color{editorBlue}}

\begin{document}

\section{Dokumenttyp <!DOCTYPE>}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>`\color{editorDarkOrange}HTML and CSS'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <h1>`\color{editorDarkOrange}Hantering av olika språk'</h1>
        <p>`\color{editorDarkOrange}This is English, but \< h_dh al-l.gT al-`rbyT>'</p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, managed to solve it with that code. Final solution was `\beginR\raggedleft\fontencoding{LAE}\selectfont هذه اللخة العربية\endR` that was directly inserted into `listings` and also escaped. In addition, I also disabled the package `arabtex`, which seems to cause the issue with code in sections being formatted. The font encoding `LAE` needed to be added to the package `fontenc` as follows: `\usepackage[OT6,LAE,T1]{fontenc}`.