# Incompatibility between ctexcap and babel-arabic?

Tags: pdftex, babel, languages, ctex, multilingual

I'm trying to typeset a multilingual document with Arabic, Chinese (and a few others). In the following MWE, the Arabic word الشمس for "sun" is not shown (presumably because the `babel` package is not loaded). However, if I load the `babel` package with the `arabic` option, I get an error saying

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \I already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.155 ...ing\else\ArabicEncoding\fi\beginL#1\endL}
                                                  %
?
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I should add that, for backward compatibility reasons, I have to use the pdftex engine to compile this particular document.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctexcap}
% \usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
% English: 
Sun
% Arabic: 
الشمس
% \foreignlanguage{arabic}{الشمس}
% Chinese: 
太阳    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you *have* to use `ctex`? Why not simply use a modern font and Unicode throughout?

Comment: @Ingmar: Can you be more specific please? What would I use instead of `ctex`? I guess I should have made that clear but I'm bound to pdftex for backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: Yes, my approach would have meant to use a modern LaTeX engine, preferably LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

arabic.ldf is very old and not compatible with an unicode engine. With lualatex you can use something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[UTF8,fontset=fandol]{ctexcap}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=fonts ids]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.5,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
% English:
Sun
% Arabic:
الشمس
% \foreignlanguage{arabic}{الشمس}
% Chinese:
太阳
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have a pdftex-based solution? For backward compatibility reasons, I can't switch to lualatex for this particular document.

Comment: you can try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

Comment: See also https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html#pdftex