# Adding a few words in Urdu, Japanese and Russian to pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, unicode, russian, japanese

I'm writing an English document that has to be compiled using pdflatex.

I'd like to add a few words in Urdu, Japanese and Russian to the document. I'm using an existing template so I'd like any changes I make to be local and not global to the entire document.

I've tried the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529681/cant-write-in-arabic-package-babel-error-language-definition-file-main-arabic/529706#529706) and it seems to work, but its for Arabic and I'm not sure how to change it to support the 3 languages that I actually need.

Thanks!!!

Comment: if it is really just a few words typeset them using lualatex (or Word, or a web browser) and include the pdf using `\includegraphics` . Setting up Urdu and Japanese isn't impossible but not easy and increasingly rare as using luatex and opentype fonts is so much easier, it is unlikely to be worth it

Comment: Ok thanks, I might do that