# How to use Arabtex (or write a few Arabic text example) inside ACM template?

Tags: arabic, acm, arabtex

Using overleaf: after just inserting arabtex package the document start giving me random errors.

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}

\usepackage{arabtex}
```

--> you can find acm template here: https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

error logs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the errors will not be random, if you showed them someone could debug. You get errors form a file with just those two lines?

Comment: I get no error from `\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{arabtex}  
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}` but a warning  `### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 3 (\begingroup)`

Comment: sorry for saying that it random, but I just added one line on the original working template (\usepackage{arabtex}) and it raised the error. (sample of the errors that I get is above)

Comment: don't use screeshots, edit your example here so it is a complete small document that shows the error, and show the resulting log (from the overleaf menu) as text.

Comment: Ok, just give me a second

Comment: Thanks alot, I think I found the source of the error: 

\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{arabtex}



\begin{document}

It seem that the error raised from here: 

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}  %% <---

\end{document}
\endinput

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388