# Undefined control sequence error with arabtex package

Tags: color, unicode, arabtex

I am trying to introduce the arabtex package into my document with the following three lines:

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
```

However, including these lines in the preamble always gives an undefined control sequence error message. It pops up at around the 390th line of my code (where nothing special happens), sometimes on the line where a new section starts, sometimes where a table begins, or sometimes even on empty lines. The error message reads

```
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                              }\aftergroup \reset@color
```

Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the error in a minimal example.

My preamble looks like this. When I comment out the three arab text lines everything works fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape} 

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    position=above}

\makeatletter

\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.8\baselineskip}

% bibliography packages
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
 \bibliographystyle{apalike}

 % arab text
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: without a complete example debugging is not possible. If you want to write only a few arabic words, don't load `arabtex`, switch only the font encoding and the direction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388. If you want to write lots of arabic, switch to an unicode engine like lualatex. Side remark: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` claims that your document is still latin1 encoded, if that is true it would clash with utf8 options.