How to include arabic Unicode Point in Overleaf
So I am fairly new to overleaf and I am using it to write my master's thesis. How would I include the arabic phrase "BISMILLAH AR-RAHMAN AR-RAHEEM" in overleaf as part of my acknowledgements? I am using
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}

at the start, and then in my acknowledgment section I am using
\begin{arabtext}
            
\end{arabtext}

but haven't really had any luck so far trying to include the characters from the website below.
https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic-presentation-forms-a/fdfd/arabic-ligature-bismillah-ar-rahman-ar-raheem/
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Welcome! Is this the only Arabic in the document? What language(s) is the rest? LuaTeX would be the best option for Arabic, but if it is only a phrase and you have everything else set up, it might not be the best overall. Don't load utf8 regardless. UTF8 input is default anyway. Even if you're not using LuaTeX/XeTeX, it's default for input. That package is almost quarter of a century old. arabtex itself is almost as old. These are not good choices. Can you provide the phrase you need in Arabic?

Hi! Yes this would be the only arabic, maybe another phrase or two but it wouldn't be anymore than that. The rest of the document would be in English. The phrase I need is bismillah ar rahman ar raheem. I see you have said that those packages are old, could you advise on any newer packages? Thanks a lot!

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529706/2388

For short texts, use polyglossia, fontspec and compile with LuaLaTeX.


Compile this with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}
%\setmainfont{Brill}[
%   Scale             = 1.07,
%   Ligatures         = {Common,NoRare},%
%   SmallCapsFeatures = {RawFeature=+c2sc},%
%   Renderer          = Node,%
%   Numbers           = Lining,%
%   RawFeature={fallback=panunicode},
%]
\begin{document}

 Arabic  \textarabic{االيوم الشمس تشرق الزاهية} 
  In the Name of Allah (SWT) the Merciful, the Compassionate or 
 [\textarabic{ ﷽  }] Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem (Arabic:
 \textarabic{ 'بِسْمِ ٱللَّٰهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ) } is an Arabic phrase meaning "in the name of God, Most Gracious, Most Merciful . 
\end{document}


Thank you for the reply! Do you know how I can compile this with LuaLaTeX?

lualatex   yourdocumentname.tex  Same like pdflatex  except you use lualatex

Got it and it works! Thanks again!

Here is an option for both xelatex and lualatex, which are the recommended engines when you need non-Latin scripts:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

English text \foreignlanguage{arabic}{﷽} English text.

\end{document}


